# How to use aws provided kms Encryption Key for SQS in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-sqs, server-sent-events

I want to configure my SQS Terraform Script to use an aws provided SSE Key.
I know that you can do this with the follwing code:

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "terraform_queue" {
  name                              = "terraform-example-queue"
  kms_master_key_id                 = "alias/aws/sqs"
  kms_data_key_reuse_period_seconds = 300
}
```

But with this example I need to first create my own KMS Key. In the aws console it is possible to use a default one without creating one by myself. How do I do this in Terraform, what do I have to type in `kms_master_key_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default key for any service is given by the alias `alias/aws/$service`. So when you refer to `alias/aws/sqs` you're using the default AWS managed KMS key for that service in that region.

This is briefly covered in the [AWS user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/create-keys.html):

> The alias name cannot begin with aws/. The aws/ prefix is reserved by Amazon Web Services to represent AWS managed CMKs in your account.